# update to 'unvaccinated' only if table1.Vaccinated = 'YES' for the row that said yes AND don't update for people that said no

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DROP TABLE table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(
    Vaccinationstatus VARCHAR(10),
    Vaccinated VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (Vaccinationstatus)
VALUES ('yes');

SELECT * FROM table1;

UPDATE table1
SET table1.Vaccination_status = 'Vaccinated'
WHERE table1.Vaccinated = 'yes'

UPDATE table1
SET table1.Vaccination_status = 'Vaccinated'
CASE
WHEN table1_Vaccinated = 'Yes'
ELSE Vaccination_status 
-- If the table1.Vaccinated  say 'yes' depending on the row which said yes update the table1.Vaccination_status to 'Vaccinated' for those row that said yes only--
END;
```

Error I keep getting:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I'm trying to update table1.Vaccination_status to update to `unvaccinated` only if `table1.Vaccinated = 'YES'` for the row that said yes AND don't update for people that said no.

I want to also make it so that it only update if those conditional are meet. I tried an update statement but I don't think I am doing it right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's case sensitive. So 'Yes' doesn't equal 'yes'

To be sure, you could use COLLATION, or use LOWER or UPPER.

Example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>  VictimId int, 
>  VaccinationStatus VARCHAR2(10),
>  Vaccinated VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'no'
> );
>
> INSERT ALL
> INTO table1 (VictimId, Vaccinated) VALUES (1, 'yes')
> INTO table1 (VictimId) VALUES(2)
> SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * From table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> VICTIMID | VACCINATIONSTATUS | VACCINATED
> -------: | :---------------- | :---------
>        1 | null              | yes       
>        2 | null              | no
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1
> SET VaccinationStatus = 'Vaccinated'
> WHERE lower(Vaccinated) = lower('Yes')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * From table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> VICTIMID | VACCINATIONSTATUS | VACCINATED
> -------: | :---------------- | :---------
>        1 | Vaccinated        | yes       
>        2 | null              | no
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6314964b0a2f32fee1371c76aa3598da)*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, you're missing the point of the feedback you're getting. There's a syntax error: you're missing a semi-colon at the end of one of your statements:

`UPDATE table1 SET table1.Vaccination_status = 'Vaccinated' WHERE table1.Vaccinated = 'yes';`

Aside from that, indeed make sure to spell 'Yes' and 'yes' in the same manner. I'd recommend using a numerical column with either values 0 (no, false) or 1 (yes, true). That'll prevent these types of common mistakes.